# Using a string literal as a template parameter for a computed property name

Tags: typescript

Lets say i have a few objects each of which contain some property whose type is similar

```js
interface Stuff<T> {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: T;
}

type ThingOne {
  one: Stuff<string>;
}

type ThingTwo {
  two: Stuff<number>;
}

type ThingThree {
  three: Stuff<boolean>;
}
```

Is there some way i can parameterize the property name using generics?
I was thinking something along the lines of:

```js
interface Thing<T, U> {
  [key: U]: Stuff<T>;
}

// then

type ThingOne = Thing<string, 'one'>;
type ThingTwo = Thing<number, 'two'>;
type ThingThree = Thing<boolean, 'three'>;
```

Obviously `[key: U]` is incorrect. I cant seem to figure out what it should be or if it's even possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the build in mapped type `Record`, which takes a `string` literal type (or a union of string literal types) which will be the property names, and the type for the member:

```
interface Stuff<T> {
  a: number;
  b: string;
  c: T;
}

type ThingOne = Record<'one', Stuff<string>>;
type ThingTwo = Record<'two', Stuff<number>>;
type ThingThree = Record<'three', Stuff<boolean>>;
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgK4xgHgCoB8yA3gFDLJwBcyIGAtgEbQDc5yjNAzmFKAOZsKCGnjYBfUqTABPAA4o8ACwEB5ECgC8yAEoQEAeygATHAHIDGswBo0mbDh58Q-AgTayFyZQLwB3A2RtPUMTczAAmzssXDomaDcPeUUVF2UoCC1dfSNTMzAlDIgo9BicRgMDABsIOBBEoA)

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what i'm looking for.